# CS50 DNA: STR counter only works most of the time

Tags: python, cs50

Here is a mock up of the function.  A lot of the samples have one or two STRs coming back as 1. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
dnaSamp = input("DNA: ")
strSeq = ["TATC"]###["AGATC", "TTTTTTCT", "AATG", "TCTAG", "GATA", "TATC", "GAAA", "TCTG"]
hiScore = [0] * len(strSeq)
for i in range(len(strSeq)):  # cycle throught the varios STRs
    for j in range(len(dnaSamp) - (len(strSeq)-1)):  # loop over dna sample  
        k = j + len(strSeq[i])  # variable to control the length of the STR sequence
    
        if dnaSamp[j : k] == strSeq[i]:
            counter = 0
        
            for l in range(len(dnaSamp)):        #if match look at next set
                if dnaSamp[j + (l  * len(strSeq[i])) : k + (l * len(strSeq[i]))] == strSeq[i]:
                    counter += 1
                    continue
                break
            if counter > hiScore[i]:
                hiScore[i] = counter    #save highest counter
        
    print(f"{strSeq[i]} = {hiScore[i]}" )
```

Comment: post the sample input and expected output

Comment: Also, just realized that the strSeq was set just to find TATC while I was trying to debug. The normal line would read as after the comment #

Comment: i don't understand what you saying?

Comment: Please post both the expected output and the actual output for some short sample input.  Also explain what the purpose of the function is, i.e. what you are trying to do

Comment: Heya. The function is meant to loop through a sequence of DNA, a long string of chars. The function should be able to return the  the most amount of times a given sequence of letters repeats itself.  The sequences on line two are what the function is looking for (including after the ##) and the input is what I'd think is too big to post here.  The function finds the correct repeating numbers for most of the dna samples that I enter, however some come up incorrectly as 1. Always one and showing one for different str sequences for each input. I how this helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: UPDATE : I've transferred the input to word files and with the search function I've been able to figure out that the function is missing the sequences in the last 20% (ballpark) of the input. Is there any reason the loop isn't going all the way through the input?

Comment: The function worked it just didn't work with input via terminal. I'm suspecting there is a paste limit.  Thanks guys.